# System.out.println is not recognized in a maven project

Tags: java

Am working on a maven java project in netbeans,in my projects I have 2 classes where System.out.println works fine,but when I added another class
and tried to use a switch statement it couldn't accept a String so in I decided to declare a string and print out to find if the String is recognized by my class,declaration worked without error but when trying printing the string it gave me this error

cannot find symbol
symbol:class out
location:class System

and it is suggesting that I should search dependencies at Maven repository.

```
package tiw5.restaurants.service;

import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;

public class Controlleur
{
    private SOAPMessage request;
    private String serviceName = "test";

    public Controlleur(SOAPMessage request)
    {
        this.request = request;
    }

    // The line below gives me error
    System.out.println(serviceName);
}
```

Comment: actually am not telling you am asking what might be the problem I forgot to specify how can I solve this

Comment: Do you have your own class named `System`?

Comment: You haven't actually asked anything, you just chained together a bunch of statements.

Comment: @redFIVE I guess it has never happened to you that your forget  a phrase in your writtings,quite impressing know that I was taken with the title I thought I had made it the part of the question!!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch No I don't, actually I searched on google for most common cause and one of them was having the class named System which is not my case.

Comment: thank you !!ALL I had to do is to put it into a method!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you posted, the `System.out.println` is not inside of a method. Everything other than declarations needs to be inside of a method. Move it into your constructor, and it should fix the problem.

```
public class Controlleur {
    private SOAPMessage request;
    private String serviceName="test";

    public Controlleur(SOAPMessage request){
        System.out.println(serviceName);
        this.request=request;
    }
}
```